# Using gmailR with R

Tags: r, gmail

I'm struggling to find a way to send a few (likely much less than 100 per month) emails with the `gmailR` package. I set up the package with a new gmail account and the account was banned after sending two test emails using `gmailR` to another email account I had.

I am perplexed that the `gmailR` package can exist if Google is so aggressive about banning accounts that use it.

Are there users out there that use gmailR? Is it safe to use gmailR with a personal gmail account?

Tried `gmailR`, another gmail account, postmark, etc. with poor results. Have pursued purchasing a domain to try and get around this issue. I apologize if this is the wrong forum for this kind of discussion.

Comment: See: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en for some clues.

Comment: I appreciate the link, but this link discusses emails in the thousands (e.g., 2000, 5000 messages). In my post I mentioned this happened after sending 2 ("two") emails.

Comment: Again: read the post. It discusses: a) how to review account acitvity; b) best practices for senders and c) how to request restoration of a suspended account. I do not know exactly what happened in your case (suspension for 2 emails seems strange, but still within the realm of possibility if you do not adhere very closely to the recommended best practices, Google does not play when it comes to (potential) spam. You will have to do the research and speak with support, or perhaps try again with another account (which will likely result in a ban on your IP address instead).

Comment: I can say that I have send quite a few test messages (maybe 100+) and many of them with  a PDF attachment. Attachment is R-generated data analysis report in PDF format. I have not had any issues at all. YMMV, but I would be interested in your view and experience as to how this resolves.